# owl carsouel: slide 1 item, out of 3 items

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I have been trying to use owl carousel for following feature.
There are total 4 items. At a time 3 items are displaying on page.

so on clicking next, it should displace only 1 item at a time.
for example:

Currently there are 3 boxes displaying with number 1, 2, 3. On clicking next button, it should display 2, 3, 4. Then again on clicking next it should display=> 3,4,1, and so on.

I have tried following code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .item {
                height: 10rem;
                background: #4DC7A0;
                padding: 1rem;
            }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <div class="item">
                    <h4>1</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <h4>2</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <h4>3</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <h4>4</h4>
                </div> 
                <div class="item">
                    <h4>5</h4>
                </div> 
                <div class="item">
                    <h4>6</h4>
                </div> 
                <div class="item">
                    <h4>7</h4>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                items: 3, 
                loop:true,   
                //nav:true, 
                margin: 10 
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But problem is it is going as

1, 2,3 => 4,5,6 => 7, 1, 2

By how to do
1,2,3 => 2,3,4 => 3,4,5 and so on.

I have followed the [doc provided here.](http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/)

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This seems to be working correctly for me with your code. All I did was uncomment the "nav:true" line. https://jsbin.com/nuhuroriya/edit?html,output

Comment: Clicking the next/prev arrows don't slide one at a time? Or are you clicking the dots?

Comment: @TimBanks, its sliding one page at a time. My doubt is how to slide one item at a time

Comment: Are you clicking the dots or the arrows?